# NSRange can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to check if file has the word 'text', however i have encountered this error : [image: image of an error]

Is there a way to solve this?
Thanks

```
 var data = try NSString(contentsOfFile: documentsDirectoryPath as String,
        encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
        print(data)
if data.rangeOfString("text") != nil {

            print("this is text")
        }
        else{
            print("this is an error")
        }
```

Comment: It's ok to post a screenshot to show an error message, but you **have to also post the code as text** in the question. Use the [edit] button under your question to edit/add info after posting.

Comment: check for range.index != NSNotFound instead

Comment: Swift _String_ doesn't have _init(contentOfFile:encoding:)_, does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the following code to check if the string is found:

```
if data.rangeOfString("text").location != NSNotFound {

}
```

`rangeOfString` does not (yet) return `nil` when the value is not found. Instead it returns `NSNotFound`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately i get this error now : `Binary operator != cannot be applied to operands of type NSRange and Int`

Comment: shouldn't it be `if data.rangeOfString("text").location != NSNotFound {`

Comment: @vikingosegundo Yes, that part got lost in translation from my brain. Thanks!

Comment: @vikingosegundo thank you very much, it worked :) Not sure why i said it didnt work before, probs some lag in Xcode

Answer (score 4):

`rangeOfString` is declared both in Swift Standard Library (`String`) and in Foundation (`NSString`).

But they are different:

- The `NSString` version returns always a non-optional `NSRange` structure whose `location` is `NSNotFound` if the index couldn't be found.

  ```
  let data : NSString = "sourcetext"        
  if data.rangeOfString("text").location != NSNotFound {...}
  ```
- The `String` version returns an optional `Range<Index>` which is `nil` if the index couldn't be found.

  ```
  let data : String = "sourcetext"        
  if data.rangeOfString("text") != nil {...}
  ```

---

In your case you could use the Swift version by coercing the `NSString` instance to `String`.

```
    let data = try NSString(contentsOfFile...  ) as String
    if data.rangeOfString("text") != nil {...}
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. `contentsOfFile` you mentioned has to be of NSData, however my `data` is a path to the location of the file so i can't use that as an argument. Am i understanding what you are saying correctly?

Comment: In your question `let data ... ` returns the Foundation type `NSString`. My suggestion is to coerce the type to Swift `String` to be able to use the Swift `rangeOfString()` which can be `nil` and returns optional `Range<Index>`